# insert checkbox checked value to textbox in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have a 45 checkboxes in webform with values 1 to 45 i want ...to insert checkbox checked value to textbox in comma seperated string as in ascending order as 1,2,3,4,5 ...if checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3, checkbox4 and checkbox5 is checked...if these checkboxes will be unchecked then the inserted value in textbox will be removed 1 by one respectively. ..

hwo to do this using vb.net or jquery or javascript ..

Comment: Looks like it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191550/how-to-insert-checkbox-checked-text-to-textbox-as-1-2-3-using-vb-net

Answer (score 3):

Since this sounds like homework - I'll just provide you with some instructions:

- Use a [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) to separate your comma-delimited list into an array
- Use jQuery's [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method on the array to iterate through the checked
- Then use a [$(this).attr('checked',true)](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) on each of those values

**Updated with Code and Example:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   var stringOfNumbers = "1,3,5,7";
   var split = stringOfNumbers.split(',');
   $.each(split, function(index, value)
   { 
       $("input[id='"+value+"']").attr('checked',true);
   });
});
```

**Function**

```
    function CheckTheseBoxes(stringOfNumbers)
    {
       var split = stringOfNumbers.split(',');
       $.each(split, function(index, value)
       { 
           $("input[id='"+value+"']").attr('checked',true);
       });
    }
```

**Code Explanation:**

> The stringOfNumbers holds your
>   comma-delimited string with all of
>   your numbers to select,  the
>   stringOfNumbers.split(',') separates
>   all of the values in the string and
>   stores them  in an Array. The $.each()
>   method iterates through all of the
>   values in the splitArray (the values
>   that will determine which checkboxes
>   are checked.
>
> Inside the loop - a jQuery  selector
>   is built specifying the selection of
>   an "input" where id is equal to value,
>   value being the id to select. Finally,
>   the .attr('checked',true) actually
>   selects the   checkbox.

**Working Demo:**

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bxpep/2)

**Links regarding jQuery and getting started with jQuery**

[Beginning with jQuery - A Solid Foundation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

[jQuery.com](http://www.jquery.com)

Comment: why you are using 1,3,5,7 //// what to do if i use 45 checkboxes ?

Comment: That is your comma delimited string - that was just an example. You could either a.) Put your string there or b.) Use a function to take in your string and process it. I'll show you an example of the latter answer.

Comment: I updated the demo and added a function in there. Just type your string into the input and hit the button to check the boxes you typed in.